# Splitting a commit in GIT

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm really new to Git (and we're using TortiseGit), but here's my issue.  I have 3 environments: Dev, QA and Production.  The client requested two changes so I made both changes in Dev, committed them and pushed it to the QA environment.  Now the company wants one change to go to Production now and the next one to wait on a change to another system.  How do I push just part of the commit to Prod?

Comment: You can't (atleast, not technically, but you could 'work around' it). And be careful with pushing commits directly to the production environment, this should only be done for real hotfixes which can't wait.

Comment: What do you mean by "You can't"?

Comment: @OP are you working with branches?

Comment: Poor man's solution: push a commit which undoes the change you don't want to release, do the release, push a commit which puts the change back. The fact that the commit has already left your local environment makes it quite tricky to manipulate, its may not be worth the head ache.

Comment: @PeeHaa, some?  My understanding (probably flawed) is that I make a branch, make my changes, merge it back into the trunk and then push it to the next environment.

Comment: @pbond, what do you mean you shouldn't push commits directly to the production environment?  How else would you get the final code into production?

Comment: @PeeHaa that you simply can't split a commit.

Comment: @KobinBingham http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commits themselves are atomic, so they can't be split or broken up.  However since a commit is just a collection of changes, we can split up those changes and then create separate commits that just include the changes that you would want for each.

One way of doing this is to just do a soft reset to the commit before the one that you would want to split up, then stage each set of changes and commit separately.

If you already pushed your commits before breaking them up.  You would need to do a force push because you're replacing the old commit with the broken down commits so make sure to pull before doing any changes.

Agree'd with PeeHaa, you would want to create different branches for each environment and then you could just cherry pick the desired commits.

Answer (score 10):

I've used TortoiseGit 2.8 to split a commit that's on the master branch. There are quite a few steps, but they do flow decently well:

1. Right click and show log "TortoiseGit" => "Show Log".
2. Right click a commit **before** the commit you want to split.
3. Select "Rebase "master" onto this...(G)"
4. Click the checkbox to enable "Force Rebase". All the commits before the one you right clicked should now appear above the checkbox you clicked.
5. Right click the commit you want to split and select "Edit". This will change it's rebase type to "Edit", instead of "Pick".
6. Click "Start Rebase". After the progress bar kicks off, this will present you with a dialog to edit the Commit message.
7. Click to enable the "Edit/Split commit" checkbox beneath the progress bar.
8. Press the "Amend" button.
9. Uncheck the files you don't want included in the first commit.
10. Commit the first commit. Then you'll be presented with another commit for the files not included in the first commit.
11. After all files have been committed you'll be presented with a dialog asking for another commit. I'm not sure why this dialog pops up, but I always respond with no more commits.

Comment: Your post was REALLY precious! Thanks

Comment: Perfectly complete step-by-step guide which holds to this day!
Additional kudos for the last, eleventh bullet.